# Yet another Django and jQuery autocomplete newbie

Tags: django, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

After a while searching similar questions in stackoverflow, and trying different 'fixes' I must say I'm stucked in here. I'm just trying to achieve a simple autocomplete feature using jQuery-ui, but somehow, it does not display any autocompleted names, althought there are a few loaded in the db. I show you my logic and template.

**models.py**

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
  nombre = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  facultad = models.ForeignKey(Facultad, null=False, blank=False)
  carrera = models.ForeignKey(Carrera, null=False, blank=False)
  dni = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
  direccion = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  telefono = models.CharField(max_length=64)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
  fechaingreso = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)
  creadopor = models.ForeignKey(User, default=0)

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.nombre
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^get_usuarios/', 'get_usuarios', name='get_usuarios'),
```

**prestar.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#usuarios").autocomplete({
    source: "{% url get_usuarios %}",
    minLength: 2,
  });
});
```

```
<div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="usuarios">Usuarios: </label>
      <input id="usuarios">
    </div>

<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>
```

(This last part is heredated from base.html, and it is located at the end of the template)

**views.py**

```
def get_usuarios(request):
  if request.is_ajax():
      q = request.GET.get('term', '')
      usuarios = Usuario.objects.filter(nombre__icontains=q)[:20]
      results = []
      for usuario in usuarios:
          usuario_json = {}
          usuario_json['id'] = usuario.id
          usuario_json['label'] = usuario.nombre
          usuario_json['value'] = usuario.nombre
          results.append(usuario_json)
      data = simplejson.dumps(results)
  else:
      data = 'fail'
  mimetype = 'application/json'
  return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

In particular I have doubts about if this

```
usuario_json['id'] = usuario.id
usuario_json['label'] = usuario.nombre
usuario_json['value'] = usuario.nombre
```

Is correct, as I couldn't realize what they exactly are meant to be.

*Thanks to anyone wishing to iluminate me!*

Comment: One issue I've just solved is that in this line: <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min"></script> I missed .js at the end of the file. Of course, I corrected that but still not getting the functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autosolved, as usual, dumb mistake. Should import jQuery-ui **BEFORE** using it.